# How to output every number from 1 to 10. Using random numbers in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, random

I am trying to make a script which is outputting every number from 1-10.
Using a random number generator, in JavaScript.

I want every number to be unique.
Here is an example of what i would like the script to output:

```
5 9 7 6 1 3 4 8 2 10
```

This is my attempt:

```
    var test = [];
    var amountOfNumbers = 10;
    var inArray = false;
    var useNumbers = [];
    for(var i=0; useNumbers.length<=amountOfNumbers; i++){
        var rng = Math.floor((Math.random()*amountOfNumbers)+1);
        for(var a=0; a<=test.length; a++){
            if(rng == test[a]){
                inArray == true;
            }
        }
        if(!inArray){
            document.write(rng);
            test.push(rng);
            useNumbers.push(rng);
        }
    }
```

Hope you can help.

for the record I am not interested in jQuery og any other library :)

Comment: Generate the numbers from one to ten, and then shuffle them: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2450954/how-to-randomize-shuffle-a-javascript-array

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**1) How to fix your code**

You have a few errors, among them the fact you don't reset `inArray` to `false` and that you don't iterate over the whole `test` array (use `<`, not `<=`). But using a loop to see if you already have the number isn't efficient, it's better to use an object as a map :

```
var test = [];
var amountOfNumbers = 10;
var useNumbers = {};
for(var i=0; test.length<amountOfNumbers; i++){
        var rng = Math.floor((Math.random()*amountOfNumbers)+1);
        if(!useNumbers[rng]){
            document.write(rng);
            test.push(rng);
            useNumbers[rng] = true;
        }
}
```

**2) How to do it properly**

Your algorithm will loop until it is lucky enough to find the remaining numbers. This isn't efficient and isn't predictable. The normal reliable practice is

1. to generate the array [1..10]
2. to shuffle it

Generating an array of the integers from 1 to `N` can be done with a simple loop or in a fancier way :

```
var arr = Array.apply(0,new Array(N)).map(function(_,i){ return i+1 });
```

Shuffling an array is usually done with the [Fisher-Yates algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher-Yates_shuffle), for which you'll easily find JS implementations (it's easy to write anyway). A fast (theoretically not guaranteed to work with all future `sort` implementations) alternative is this one :

```
arr = arr.sort(function(a,b){ return Math.random()>0.5 });
```

[The whole program](http://jsbin.com/kuzav/1/edit)

Comment: Great way to generate an ordered array in just one line. Upvoting!

Comment: @adripanico Did you notice my whole program, including the shuffing, is two lines ?

Comment: Ahh I didn't notice the edition. Should I delete my answer?

Comment: @adripanico I don't know. Only you can decide.

Answer (score 1):

Your approach means to check over all the array in each step, looking if your random number is already inside the array, which means a lot lost time.

Best approach is disordering an ordered array. In each loop, we generate a random number (in the example, a number between 0 and 1) and with a 50% probability we change the item in the current position for other item in a random position (between 0 and the length of the array).

Hope it helps.

```
function disorder(arg) {
  for (var i = 0; i < arg.length; i++) {
      if (Math.random() < 0.5) {
          var aux = arg[i];
          var rndPos = Math.floor(Math.random()) * arg.length;
          arg[i] = arg[rndPos];
          arg[rndPos] = aux;
      }
  }
  return arg;
}

var myArray = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10];

var myNewArray = disorder(myArray);

myNewArray.forEach(function(item) {
  console.log(item);
});
```